# SQL Server 2008: creating a supervisor hierarchy in Cognos

Tags: sql-server-2008, cognos

I have a list of employees and with a list of immediate supervisors in the table. I want to create a select statement (I am limited because I am not using SQL Server directly just it as an engine) that not only produces the immediate supervisor but a supervisors supervisor in the next column. I have titles but I want to create one that is not limited by titles and or levels of management. Even just suggestions to try would be helpful.

This is how I started (the were clause is just so I can test data).  I plan on flipping it too a two column select statement. I am not sure

```
SELECT PayeeID, tblLevel1.Sup1, Sup2
From (SELECT PayeeID ,SupervisorID AS Sup1
FROM PayeeHRAttribute
Where AsOfDate ='10/31/2015') AS tblLevel1 Right Join (Select PayeeID as Sup1, SupervisorID AS Sup2
FROM PayeeHRAttribute
Where AsOfDate = '10/31/2015') AS tblLevel2 On tblLevel1.Sup1 = tblLevel2.Sup1
```

Comment: I am thinking of maybe adding fields next to the original payeeID and then converting it back into a two column table

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 queries in Report Studio (look into Queries tab) and join them.
First table

```
supervisor
employee
```

Second table

```
supervisor as supersupervisor
employee as supervisor
```

Join it by supervisor field.
Create list with fields

```
employee
supervisor
supersupervisor
```

Comment: SELECT PayeeID, tblLevel1.Sup1, Sup2
From (SELECT PayeeID ,SupervisorID AS Sup1
FROM PayeeHRAttribute
Where AsOfDate ='10/31/2015') AS tblLevel1 Right Join (Select PayeeID as Sup1, SupervisorID AS Sup2
FROM PayeeHRAttribute
Where AsOfDate = '10/31/2015') AS tblLevel2 On tblLevel1.Sup1 = tblLevel2.Sup1

Comment: You are doing it wrong.
You don't need no write SQL to do you task.
As I said. Create 2 queries and join it in report. Read the doc how to do it.

Comment: but writing SQL is so fun I don't mean to troll I just wanted to find a SQL Solution to build my SQL skills because they are more transferable.

Comment: It's not a Cognos BI way. And normally it's prohibited to use direct SQL in Report Studio